# bash error: 2: integer expression expected

Tags: linux, bash, shell, integer, debian

I have a problem with a simple bash script..

```
#!/bin/bash
libc_main_ver=$(dpkg -l |grep libc6 |awk '{print$3}' |awk -F .
'{print$1}'|xargs -n 1)
if [ "$libc_main_ver" -eq 2 ] ;then
echo ok
else 
echo nope
fi
exit  0
```

When i try execute the script it gives me the error:

```
2: integer expression expected
```

What's the problem?

```
dpkg -l |grep libc6 |awk '{print$3}' |awk -F . '{print$1}'|xargs -n 1
```

This prints only 2 not other values.

Some suggestions?

Comment: What does `dpkg -l | grep libc6` output?

Comment: ii  libc6:amd64                           2.13-38+deb7u7                     amd64        Embedded GNU C Library: Shared libraries ad others libc dependences but ofc more then 500 characters :(

Comment: AAARGH! "This prints only 2 not other values" was extremely misleading. "This prints only several 2's, no other values ('2 2 2 2 2')". Of course "2 2 2 2 2" does not compare equal to "2". Apparently you also botched the error message by not writing *exactly* what was printed. Please do this very carefully next time you have a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
libc_main_vers=$(dpkg -l | grep libc6 | awk '{ print $3 }' | awk -F . '{ print $1 }')
for ver in ${libc_main_vers}; do
    if (( ver == 2 )); then
        echo ok
    else
        echo nope
    fi
done
exit 0
```

Comment: Nope with -f 3 (libc6:amd64
libc6:i386
libc6-dev:amd64
libc6-i386
libc6-i686:i386
)it print name and architecture and with -f 2  nothing get parsed

Comment: @Nhoya, sorry, I don't have Ubuntu, so I am doing it blind folded based on what you posted in the comment. Is this the exact line for glibc: `ii libc6:amd64 2.13-38+deb7u7 amd64 Embedded GNU C Library: Shared libraries`?

Comment: Debian, not Ubuntu.. btw (ii  libc6:amd64                           2.13-38+deb7u7                     amd64        Embedded GNU C Library: Shared libraries
)

Comment: @Nhoya, I found a Mint box and found out there are multiple spaces in between the words, which is why the `cut` was failing. So I changed it to `awk` instead

Comment: ok, it works but it gives me only 1 result.. dpkg -l |grep libc6 gives me 4 lines then i need 4 "2" and not only one

uuups head -n 4 10

Comment: Nope, it don't want parse more then one argoument :\ What wrong?

Comment: @Nhoya, please state your question more clearly. I don't understand what you are trying to do. Why do you need 4 lines? Do you have multiple versions of glibc on your computer? If not (which is most likely the case), then my original answer should solve your problem

Comment: Practically i need to see the version of all the libc6 in the system then i want print the first number and see if the is equal to 2, take the lat number 7 (is the last update) and see if it's eq or gt then 7, There are more version of libc6 indeed if i give dpkg -l !grep libc6 it gives me 4 other verions (dev, i386, i686), Yes, you can say me: but these are dendencies and if you update the system all of them had the same version, i say: yes, but you can make pinning

Comment: _i need to see the version of all the libc6 in the system_ Not really. You cannot have different versions of glibc installed on your system, so checking one is enough. I will update my answer

Answer (score 3):

Insert

```
echo "<$libc_main_ver>"
```

after the first line and the error will be obvious. Very likely there's a space or newline in there somewhere which you shouldn't numerically compare with 2.

Very esoteric: the problem could be the literal in `-eq 2` as well. If it is followed by a carriage return character, I can somewhat reproduce your error message:

```
$ test "2" -eq 2^R
bash: test: 2: integer expression expected
```

where `^R` is a literal carriage return entered with CTRL-V CTRL-R. To verify or exclude this, run `od -bc nameofyourscript`

Comment: ofcourse it print only 2.. i really continue to not understand what is the problem...

Comment: if i pull off the double quotes it gives me too many argouments error

Comment: @Nhoya If pulling off the quotes gives you a too many arguments error then `$libc_main_ver` contains more than just the string "2". Show us the output of this echo when added right before the failing comparison.

Comment: Maybe there are indeed invisible funny characters in there. To test, show us the result of `echo "<$libc_main_ver>" | od -b`

Comment: /foo
./foo: line 4: [: 2
2
2
2
2: integer expression expected
0000000 074 062 012 062 012 062 012 062 012 062 076 012
0000014

Comment: Okay, that's proof there's more than one "2" in your $libc_main_ver; they are all followed by newlines (012 = newline, 062 = "2").

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version:

```
#!/bin/bash
libc_full=$(dpkg -l | grep libc6 | head -n 1 | awk '{ print $3 }')

libc_main=$(echo ${libc_full} | grep -o "^[0-9]*")
libc_update=$(echo ${libc_full} | grep -o "[0-9]*$")

if (( libc_main == 2 )); then
    echo "Main version is OK"
    if (( libc_update >= 7 )); then
        echo "Update version is OK"
        exit 0
    fi
fi
exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether you require all the packages you list to have a major version number 2, or are just verifying that at least one of them does.

Anyway, if we start with the observation that `grep foo | awk { print $1 }` can usually be refactored into a single Awk script `awk '/foo/ { print $1 }'` we can already simplify your script; but it sometimes makes sense to refactor basically all of it into Awk.  Perhaps like this:

```
dpkg -l 'libc6*' | awk '$3 !~ /^2\./ { exit 1 }' && echo ok || echo nope
```

If you are satisfied with just one package meeting the condition, change to something like

```
dpkg -l 'libc6*' | awk '$3 ~ /^2\./ { exit 0 } END { exit 1 }' && echo ok || echo nope
```

As always, `foo && success || failure` is a shorthand for

```
if foo; then
    success
else
    failure
fi
```

where the longhand probably makes sense if your real script needs to do something moderately more complex than just echo a value.

Do note that the output from `dpkg -l` is not necessarily suitable for scripts.  Maybe use `dpkg-query -f '${Version}\n' -W 'libc6'` instead for robustness.